# Angular nested objects - TypeError: Cannot read property 'app' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pug

I have nested objects like below:

```
$scope.userForm.app.status = 'Scheduled';
$scope.userForm.app.recurring = 'One-off';
```

But I'm getting below error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'app' of undefined
```

Is there a way to get define this so errors do not occur?

I've tried doing things like `$scope.userForm.app = {}` but not sure if this is the right solution?

I also have below:

```
input.form-control#status(ng-model='userForm.status', name='status', type='text', disabled='')
```

and in controller

```
$scope.userForm = {};
$scope.userForm.status = 'Scheduled';
```

This however does not bind with model correctly and does not output Scheduled in the form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is saying `userForm` is undefined. Read the error message carefully carefully. cannot read property `app` of undefined. So you need to set `userForm` to an object:

```
$scope.userForm = {
  app: {
    status: 'Scheduled',
    recurring: 'One-off'
  }
};
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work under form with ng-controller specified like `form.form-horizontal(ng-controller='ARScheduleCtrl', role='form', name='userForm', ng-submit='submitForm()', validate-form='', novalidate='').mb-lg` how do we make it work inside form?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? You shouldn't set form properties like that.

Comment: Sorry. Don't really know much about jade. I'd recommend posting a new question as your question didn't even mention jade.

Comment: No worries but this has nothing to do with Jade because it's just HTML template generator. So I'm getting something like `<form ng-controller="ARScheduleCtrl" role="form" name="userForm" ng-submit="submitForm()" validate-form="" novalidate="" class="form-horizontal mb-lg ng-scope ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">`

Comment: Basically when I put {{userForm.app.status}} inside the form element it doesn't output but it works if it's NOT inside the form

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70569/discussion-between-wayne-ellery-and-passionate-developer).